ERROR Warning: BottomTabNavigator: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release
When i updated my expo from 50 to 51, i am having belor error and it's coming from react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar
ERROR  Warning: BottomTabNavigator: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
in BottomTabNavigator (created by App)
in App (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in CardSheet (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Animated(View))
in Animated(View) (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Animated(View))
in Animated(View) (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Card)
in Card (created by CardContainer)
in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by CardStack)
in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by HomeNavigator)
in HomeNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)
I have tried removing node  module and installing again and also i have tried upgrading package but  it did not work

Please reformat the question content.
